# how to add assembly DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessin in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, ms-word

I want to read a doc file and do some operation and I found a code, but it has asking following  "WordprocessingDocument" namespace.Has anyone know from where I can find this assembly.please dont sent me a download link for .dll file because it not good to add third party .dll directly.

Comment: I found the solution. from where that .dll is coming from :
[http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30425]

Comment: What do you mean by "please dont sent me a download link for .dll file because it not good to add third party .dll directly." OpenXml is Third party open source dll you need to download it and refer it in the project.

Comment: Oh Really.I thought that it not good to add third party .dll.anyway I dont know much details about that dll.thanks for infromation.If it is opensource dll I can Use it.

Answer (score 2):

you can download "Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office" from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425

for using this lib go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As per recent updates and methods for adding any namespaces related to **Open XML SDK** please add name spaces like *System.IO.Packaging*, *DocumentFormat.OpenXml* etc **via Nuget Package**. You can find nuget package on https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/

To Install this Nuget Package you can open Nuget Package Mananger console (**Tools** -> **Nuget Package Manager** -> **Nuget Package Manager Console)** and make sure that you have right project selected in console dropdown.

Run the following command. 
`Install-Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml`

Alternatively you can also install it via Nuget Package Manager GUI which you can open simply by Right clicking on Solution Explorer and going in 'Manage Nuget Packages'